# fetching fullcalender events from mysql db

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar

hi i am fetching events from my db table leaves...it was working fine when i fetched the data using one table but when i tried to  fetch the events from two diff tables it showed nothing...the working code when i was able to fetch the events through leave table is given below....

```
$sql_get_leaves="SELECT * from employee_leaves";
$query_leaves=mysql_query($sql_get_leaves);
$events_1=array();
while($res=mysql_fetch_array($query_leaves))
{
    $e=array();
    $e['title']="Leave";
    $e['start']=$res['leave_starting_date'];
    $e['end']=$res['leave_ending_date'];
    $e['allDay']=false;
    $e['color']=red;
    array_push($events_1,$e);
    echo json_encode($events_1);
}
```

everything was working till this point
but when i tried to fetch the data using two tables it showed me nothing

```
$sql_get_cmp_id="SELECT company_id from company where company_name='$sup_company_name'LIMIT 1";
$query_id=mysql_query($sql_get_cmp_id);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($query_id);
$company_id=$row['company_id'];
$sql_get_holidays="SELECT * from holidays where holiday_company_id='$company_id'";
$sql_holiday_query=mysql_query($sql_get_holidays);
$events_2=array();
while ($result=mysql_fetch_array($sql_holiday_query)) 
{
    # code...
    $holiday=array();
    $holiday['title']=$result['holiday_name'];
    $holiday['start']=$result['holiday_date'];
    $holiday['allDay']=false;
    $holiday['color']=green;
    array_push($events_2,$holiday);
    echo json_encode($events_2);
}
```

kindly tell me how should i solve this issue anxiously waiting for someone's responce

Comment: why dont u use a join between company and holidays

Comment: hard to say why it's showing nothing, but I don't think it's specifically to do with using two tables. Have you checked your queries are actually returning data?

Comment: also mysql_query (and associated queries) are now deprecated. If you're writing new code, you should be using mysqli or PDO.

Comment: @ADyson i got it working brother

Comment: @ADyson i have another question...

Comment: @TalhaSarwar what's your other question?